# Windows Store Apps playing Background Audio with MediaElement

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

In my Windows Phone 8.1 App, I am using Media Element. I want it to continue to play Audio even if user navigated away from app. MediaElement is using video from remote source (.mp4) file. I also tried with sample video in here;
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=272585

I followed example in [How to play audio in the background (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj841209.aspx) but could not make it work. This example is specific to Windows 8.1 not Windows Phone.

While MediaElement is playing Video Clip when I press Windows button audio stops and when I hit back it continues to work.

My code is like below;

```
     <MediaElement x:Name="MediaElement"  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" 
            MediaEnded="MediaElement_MediaEnded" 
            MediaFailed="MediaElement_MediaFailed" 
    MediaOpened="MediaElement_MediaOpened" SeekCompleted="MediaElement_SeekCompleted"   
DownloadProgressChanged="MediaElement_OnDownloadProgressChanged"  BufferingProgressChanged="MediaElement_BufferingProgressChanged" 
AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" CurrentStateChanged="MediaElement_CurrentStateChanged"    />
```

I have also defined Audio as Supported task Types in Package.appxmanifest

```
public VideoPlayer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            #region SystemMediaTransportControls
            // Hook up app to system transport controls.
            systemControls = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();
            systemControls.ButtonPressed += SystemControls_ButtonPressed;
            // Register to handle the following system transpot control buttons.
            systemControls.IsPlayEnabled = true;
            systemControls.IsPauseEnabled = true;
            systemControls.IsStopEnabled = true;
            systemControls.IsEnabled = true;
            #endregion

            _navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
            _navigationHelper.LoadState += NavigationHelper_LoadState;
            _navigationHelper.SaveState += NavigationHelper_SaveState;
        }


void SystemControls_ButtonPressed(SystemMediaTransportControls sender, SystemMediaTransportControlsButtonPressedEventArgs args)
        {
            switch (args.Button)
            {
                case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Play:
                    PlayMedia();
                    break;
                case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Stop:
                    StopMedia();
                    break;
                case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Pause:
                    PauseMedia();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private async void StopMedia()
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                MediaElement.Stop();
            });
        }

        async void PlayMedia()
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                MediaElement.Play();
            });
        }

        async void PauseMedia()
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                MediaElement.Pause();
            });
        }



private void MediaElement_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("MediaElement.CurrentState: " + MediaElement.CurrentState);
            }
            switch (MediaElement.CurrentState)
            {
                case MediaElementState.Playing:
                    systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Playing;
                    break;
                case MediaElementState.Paused:
                    systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Paused;
                    break;
                case MediaElementState.Stopped:
                    systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Stopped;
                    break;
                case MediaElementState.Closed:
                    systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Closed;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone doesn't use the same mechanism for Background Audio as Windows does, primarily because low-spec phones don't have enough resources to run two apps at once.

Instead, Windows Phone uses a dedicated background process to play music in the background. See the [`BackgroundMediaPlayer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.playback.backgroundmediaplayer.aspx) for more information on how to do this in a Windows Runtime phone app.