# How to switch from MediaElement to BackgroundMediaPlayer on Application lose focus

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have a music player page like PlayMusic.xaml and it uses `MediaPlayer` element to play music.

I want to switch `BackgroundMediaPlayer` whenever user clicks back button or Windows Button or Lock Screen.

I also would like to continue where ever song is remained. (Like `BackgroundMediaPlayer` should continue from 30th second)

Is there any mechanism in Windows phone like when ever when I lose focus from `MediaPlayer` I can switch to `BackgroundMediaPlayer` and continue playing music?

Note: I can directly use `BackgroundMediaPlayer` then it always plays music but on this case I cannot use `MediaPlayer` in PlayMusic.xaml which gives ability to watch video clip, fullscreen and seek controls.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific mechanism for this that I know of. You can build one yourself, but it is not simple:

1. First, you need to have a working background audio task and know how to communicate with it (this is not easy in itself, [this example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/BackgroundAudio-63bbc319) helped me a bit).
2. When you start playing anything in the `MediaPlayer`, your background audio task gets canceled. When you use it again, its `Run` method is called once more in the same process. Because of this, the background task must have its lifecycle properly managed, i.e. you need to subscribe to events and get a deferral in the `Run` method, and unsubscribe from events, call `BackgroundMediaPlayer.Shutdown()` and release the deferral in the `Cancel` event. Also, I found that I need to subscribe to `BackgroundMediaPlayer.MessageReceivedFromBackground` in the foreground process again after the task is restarted, because the restart seems to clear it.
3. You can detect that the `MediaPlayer` "lost focus" (and start background playback) when the page is being navigated from. However, this will not cover the case of the user multitasking away from your application or the case of the screen being turned off. You can catch these using the `CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Activated` event.
4. When you are switching to background audio, you need to pass it the current position. This can be done using messaging (`BackgroundMediaPlayer.SendMessageToBackground`).
5. You can start the background playback on the specified position by turning `AutoPlay` off and setting the position after `MediaOpened` fires.

I hope this helps. I am still battling with this (it is one giant trial and error endeavor), but it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

In Your Package Manifest you need to go to **Declarations Tab** and select **Background Tasks** and then select **Audio** and also select an entry point for your applications.

**Inside Your Xaml**

```
<MediaElement AutoPlay="True"
    AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
    x:Name="musicPlayer"
    Source="Assets/video1.mp4"
    AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia"
    CurrentStateChanged="MusicPlayer_CurrentStateChanged"/>
```

**Code Behind C#**

```
SystemMediaTransportControls systemControls;

public BlankPage7()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    // Hook up app to system transport controls.
    systemControls = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();
    systemControls.ButtonPressed += SystemControls_ButtonPressed;

    // Register to handle the following system transpot control buttons.
    systemControls.IsPlayEnabled = true;
    systemControls.IsPauseEnabled = true;

}

private void SystemControls_ButtonPressed(SystemMediaTransportControls sender, SystemMediaTransportControlsButtonPressedEventArgs args)
{
    switch (args.Button)
    {
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Play:
            PlayMedia();
            break;

        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Pause:
            PauseMedia();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

private void MusicPlayer_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (musicPlayer.CurrentState)
    {
        case MediaElementState.Playing:
            systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Playing;
            break;

        case MediaElementState.Paused:
            systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Paused;
            break;

        case MediaElementState.Stopped:
            systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Stopped;
            break;

        case MediaElementState.Closed:
            systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Closed;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

async void PlayMedia()
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
    musicPlayer.Play();
    });
}

async void PauseMedia()
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
    musicPlayer.Pause();
    });
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (systemControls != null)
    {
        systemControls.ButtonPressed -= SystemControls_ButtonPressed;
        systemControls.IsPlayEnabled = false;
        systemControls.IsPauseEnabled = false;

        systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Closed;
    }
}
```

This would i hope solve your purpose... For further details you can refer [MSDN Link.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn263187.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for info, but I am specifically asking for Windows Phone 8.1. The solution you gave works for Windows Store Apps. (Not Phone) Please see my related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28185424/windows-store-apps-playing-background-audio-with-mediaelement